# Validate if last record was created within last minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I validate the last record was not created in the last minute?

Model:

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :author_id, :presence  => true
    belongs_to :author
    before_save :check_timestamp

    def check_timestamp    
      IF last_record.created_at(<=1 minute) THEN
         DO NOT SAVE RECORD 
    end 
end
```

It's been awhile since I've picked up this project...not sure if I can do the something like above.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activerecord (4.0.1, 3.2.9)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
...
rails (4.0.1, 3.2.9)
railties (4.0.1, 3.2.9)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :author_id, :presence  => true
    belongs_to :author
    validate :check_timestamp

    def check_timestamp    
      if Posts.last.created_at > 1.minute.ago
         errors.add(:created_at, 'Something went wront')
      end
    end 
end
```

Comment: Logic looks good...but getting undefined local variable or method `last_record'

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to check if it's the last record if it's the most recent record right? so why not just check the creation date of all records and see if any exceeds the 1 minute limit,

```
class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author

    validate :check_timestamp
    validates :author_id, presence: true

    def check_timestamp    
      if Posts.where('created_at > ?' 1.minute.ago).exist?
         errors.add(:created_at, 'Something went wront')
      end
    end
end
```

I was worried it might be slower but when i benchmaked it against the `.last` method it was a lot faster, you could check it your self.

when i thought about it it does make sence, because rails doesn't waste time parsing the return query into a `Post` object then check the `created_at`, the database returns `true` or `false` directly.

Comment: Imagine a database with 1 million posts. Check all posts will be faster than get last one?

Comment: To be honest I tried it on a small table, like I said you could experiment your self, but I think if the created at column is indexed it will always be fast

Comment: If the created_at is indexed it will be faster than non indexed. But Post.last will order posts by id desc and get first one using an already existent index.

Comment: yea you are right, i guess in bigger table parsing the object will be faster than checking all the records, i wish i could add something in the `where` to indicate that i want to check the last record only.